# Unusual results for lmer: standard errors and correlation of fixed effects

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multivariate-analysis

I have a multivariate repeated measure mixed effect model that I'm getting strange results for. The ICC of my model is .1, which suggests that possibly there is no need to adjust for any nesting in the data. I have *variable* which is the combination of each dv dummy coded and is a factor, and my *Time* is which are the three time points is also a factor

However, when I run the model, each of the standard errors for my fixed effects at their respective time points are the same:

```
Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error        df t value    
DV1                         3          0.2151  248.8623  x
DV2                         5          0.2151  248.8623  x
DV3                        10          0.2151  248.8623  x
DV1:Time2                   1          0.2314 2165.0674  x
DV2:Time2                   2          0.2314 2165.0674  x 
DV3:Time2                   4          0.2314 2165.0674  x
DV1:Time3                   1          0.2364 2175.7468  x    
DV2:Time3                   2          0.2364 2175.7468  x    
DV3:Time3                   2          0.2364 2175.7468  x
```

My correlation of fixed effects matrix:

```
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            DV1     DV2      DV3    DV1:T2   DV2:T2    DV3:T2   DV1:T3   DV2:T3
DV2          0.420                                                                
DV3          0.420   0.420                                                        
DV1:T2      -0.540   0.000   0.000                                                
DV2:T2       0.000  -0.540   0.000  0.000                                         
DV3:T2       0.000   0.000  -0.540  0.000     0.000                               
DV1:T3      -0.529  -0.001  -0.001  0.491     0.000     0.000                     
DV2:T3      -0.001  -0.529  -0.001  0.000     0.491     0.000   0.004             
DV3:T3      -0.001  -0.001  -0.529  0.000     0.000     0.491   0.004     0.004
```

Would this be because of the unnecessary fit of the lmer model? Or is something going wonky in my model fit?

To be specific, participants are nested within groups, and each participant was measured three times:

```
lmer(value ~ variable + variable:Time -1 + (1|Groups/Participants)
```

where:
value = long form of all DV's
variable = dummy code factor long form of all three DV's
Time = Discrete factor of the three time points

Comment: Is your *variable" coded as a factor in the model? Also, do you have the same number of subjects at each time point for each of the three dependent variables?

Comment: My _variable_, which is the dummy coding of my three dv's in this multivariate long format, and my _Time_  are both factors. We also have only a few missing data points, so some groups have some participants that only have 2, rather than 3, data points

Thank you for the response!